# OpenRecordSet in a function with Query Parameters

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a function that returns the number of rows (records) in a query. This function will be used in an MS Access macro. Essentially: if numrecords([QUERY NAME]) > 0, then do something. The following query works great if [QUERY NAME] doesn't have any parameters.

```
Function numrecords(sRs As String) As Long
Dim dbDb As Database
Dim rsRs As Recordset
Set rsRs = dbDb.OpenRecordset(sRs, dbOpenSnapshot)
numrecords = rsRs.RecordCount
```

I now have a form that allows users to set a date to subset the outcoming data; thus I am introducing parameters to the mix. Enough googling tells me I need to use QueryDefs. The following code 'should' work as it has the green check mark of approval for similar questions on Stack Overflow but I keep getting the Error 3219 ' Invalid Operation'. The error occurs at:
Set rsRs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

```
Function numrecords(sRs As String) As Long
Dim dbDb As Database
Dim rsRs As Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter

Set dbDb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbDb.QueryDefs(sRs)

For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next

Set rsRs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot) ' ERROR OCCURS HERE!
numrecords = rsRs.RecordCount
```

Lastly, I am trying to run this function on a query, let's call it query 2 that is built off another query (query 1) that takes in a parameter from a form. The SQL of query 1 is:

````
PARAMETERS [Forms]![Frm_EIM_Submisions]![Last_Data_Entry_Date] DATETIME;
SELECT SampleID.Matrix
  , ​SampleID.Location
  , SampleID.SampleID
  , SampleID.DateSampled AS [DATE Sampled]
  , LU_Analytes.CASnum
  , LU_Analytes.[Analyte code]
  , LU_Analytes.Analyte
  , LU_Units.[Units code]
  , LU_Units.Units
  , LU_Methods.[Method code]
  , LU_Methods.Method

FROM Location
INNER JOIN (SampleID
INNER JOIN (LU_Units
INNER JOIN (LU_Methods
INNER JOIN (LU_Analytes
INNER JOIN Data ON LU_Analytes.[Analyte code] = Data.[Analyte code]) ON LU_Methods.[Method code] = Data.[Method code]) ON LU_Units.[Units code] = Data.[Units code]) ON SampleID.SampleID = Data.[Sample ID]) ON Location.Location = SampleID.Location
WHERE ((SampleID.DateSampled)>[Forms]![Frm_EIM_Submisions]![Last_Data_Entry_Date])```
Any input would be much appreciated.
````

Comment: Hi @HansUp, I added a note as to where the error is occurring to the code but essentially-  when I try to set the recordset (rsRs) at the bottom of the code. I'll edit my question to include the query.

Comment: @HansUp, I may have figured it out. I think my second query (the one called in the function) was saved as a make table rather than a select table.

Comment: No everything works. I was so focused on query 1 that I forgot to look at the sql of query 2. numrecords(query 2) was giving me the error because query 2 was a make table. As soon as I changed query 2 to a select table then the function worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what value you feed:

```vb
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    Debug.Print prm.Name, Eval(prm.Name)
    ' prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next
```

Next, try to feed that value manually:

```vb
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    ' Set realistic date value (mm/dd/yyyy):
    prm.Value = #04/01/2021#
Next
```

That should give you a hint what to correct.

Comment: I tried Debug.Print both prm.Value and prm.Name. 
prm. Value returned 12/15/2020
prm.Name returned  [Forms]![Frm_EIM_Submisions]![Last_Data_Entry_Date]

When i try to hard code in #12/15/2020#, I once again get an error when trying to set the recordset.

Comment: Then try: `Set rsRs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)`.